# Is it OK to provide referees report from round 1 to a new referee in round 2?

Tags: publications, peer-review

In a referee report from round 2, a new referee (ref C) mentions conclusions from round 1 reports (from ref A). Is it a common practice to provide the reports from previous rounds to a new referee? I understand this can speed up the review process, but it can also introduce some kind of bias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is standard practice that referees of a new round can see all the referee reports of the previous rounds. This includes any new referees in the pool. Without this information it would be hard to understand why certain changes were made. New referees may specifically be brought in to help adjucate divergent opinions between the previous referees.

Comment: Are identities of A and B also made available to C?

Comment: @I. M. Different venues have different rules about anonimity of reviews. Sometimes the reviewers know each other's identities, sometimes they do not.